# change page transition direction

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, gsap

I followed this tutorial on page transitions
https://youtu.be/ergc889Jghc

I’m trying to change the direction of the page transition and have each page go a different direction. I’d like to go from right to left, left to right (like the video) top to bottom, and bottom to top.
I’m having an issue where it keeps entering from the left side on default before going in the direction I want it to go. Unfortunately, I erased my code because I got frustrated so I don’t have anything to show but maybe someone can tell me how to adjust the code from the video so I can recreate it. Thanks!

Comment: If you used the code in the video, and deleted the code, the video still exists. Why not restart from what was in the video and at least post that here?